# Transition does not work when position is fixed

Tags: html, css

Click on the icon in the codepen to see the output.

I would like the container to be fixed. However when the container is fixed the transition for the X icon does not work. When I click on the menu button the X icon does not have a transition.

You need to uncomment the position fixed to see how it effects the X icon.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzxaGb

```
#container {
  display: none;
/*  Uncomment the position fixed  */
/*   position: fixed; */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 9999;  
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

#menu, #close {    
  position: absolute;
  top: 4%;
  right: 2%;  
  transition: all 0.3s linear;  
  font-size: 3em;
}

#close {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the `#menu` element need to be outside the fixed element?

Comment: It does transition (although not the element you think) but it seems to me you're trying to transition the `display` property which is not possible. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/brXzxL

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the menu icon you can change the position of the container temporary. It's not the best but it works.

Add this code:

```
menu.onclick = function() {
  container.style.position = 'static';
}

x.onclick = function() {
  container.style.position = 'fixed';
}
```

Comment: I want the container to be fixed at all times